# transparent signals over ssh

Tags: ssh, pipe, signals

By transparently I mean forwarding of:

- `stdin`, `stdout` and `stderr`
- standard signals (`SIGHUP` or `SIGINT` would be great for a start)

As an example, consider these invocations of a (pointless) local and remote command:

```
$ `cat - > /dev/null; sleep 10` < /local/file
$ ssh user@host "cat - > /dev/null; sleep 10" < /local/file
```

I can interrupt the first one with `^C` just fine. But if I try this during the second one it only affects `ssh`, leaving the command running on the remote server if `cat` has already finished.

I know about launching `ssh`with `-t`, but this way I can't send data via `stdin`. Is this possible with `ssh` alone at all?

Answer (score 0):

Signals are the domain of the local kernel; they are not ever carried across a network link.

While you can run commands in a remote ssh session from a local computer, that does not magically make the system-level events on the remote computer available locally.

You would have to wrap the entire thing in a script that traps all (possible) signals and communicates these back across the ssh connection, but even then they wouldn't magically become signals again.

Perhaps something involving `nc` would be more appropriate for shuffling std{in|out|err} across; that, too, is not part of ssh's toolset.

Comment: I have noticed that the ssh protocol supports sending of signals, and exit values. But the openssh only seems to support exit values. I expected to be able to send a signal to ssh for it to Marshall it across to the sshd that would then in turn signal the remote process.